# JQuery dynamic change margins and size on browser resize

Tags: jquery, html, margin

I have draggable divs with `position:absolute` inside an relative div.

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative;">
  <div class="child1" style="position:absolute;margin-left:580;margin-top:109;"></div>
  <div class="child2" style="position:absolute;margin-left:300;margin-top:20;"></div>
</div>
```

The positions (`margin-left` and `margin-top`) comes from this code:

```
$('#iframe_main').contents().find('.child".$key."').draggable({ 
    containment:'#parent',
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(event) {
        o = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('.child').offset();
        p = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('#parent').offset();

        childtop = o.top - p.top;
        childleft = o.left - p.left;
        console.log(childtop + " " + childleft);
}});
```

What i need is, that the absolute divs **calculate their `margin-left` and `margin-top` dynamic and also the `width` and `height`** at browser resize.

I think i have to divide #parent / 2 ?

```
var parentWidth  = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('#parent').width();

$(window).on('resize', function(){
$('#iframe_main').contents().find('.child').css('margin-left','parentwidth / 2');
});
```

I can´t use css because the childs need to have `position:absolute`.

Comment: have you tried using css only with `transform` and `translate`?

Comment: yes but the absolute div´s will be ignored. I realy think i need jquery in this case.